# back track variable in C# recursive function

Tags: c#

I have this data in same sql table. I need to create a tree look like structure for the following data. Everything seems to be working fine except the indenting is not working right. I am missing something minor which I am not able to figure out. I will appreciate any help.

This is data in same table

```
initiated_by
---------------------
 NULL,42521,42521,41651,41111,41111,41131,41651

user_id (assigned to)
---------------------
42521,41651,42681,41111,42021,41131,42001,43001
```

What I expecting is as follow.

```
42521 (at level 0)
   41651 (at level 1)
      41111 (at level 2)
        42021(at level 3)
        41131(at level 3)
          42001(at level 4)
      43001(at level 2)
   42681 (at level 1)
```

But what I am getting is not right. I am not able to figure out the indentLevel part. indentLevel is a variable declared at class level.

```
private void BuildTable(DataTable recordList)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in recordList.Rows)
        {

            TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();
            TableCell tblCell = new TableCell();

            tblCell.Controls.Add(GetDetailTable(dr, indentLevel));

            tblCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCell);
            mainTable.Rows.Add(tblRow);

            //Do we have any child objects
            int cId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["user_id"].ToString());
            DataTable dt = GetChildObjects(Convert.ToInt32(dr["user_id"].ToString()), masterDT);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) indentLevel = indentLevel+1; BuildTable(dt);

        }

    }


    private Table GetDetailTable(DataRow dr, int indentLevel)
    {

        Table DetailTable = new Table();
        DetailTable.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        DetailTable.CssClass = "SortableTable";

        TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();

        TableCell tblEmptyCell = new TableCell();
        tblEmptyCell.Width = Unit.Percentage(5);
        tblEmptyCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Empty));
        tblEmptyCell.Width = Unit.Percentage(5 * indentLevel);  
        tblRow.Cells.Add(tblEmptyCell);

        //To Display Name
        TableCell tblCell = new TableCell();
        tblCell.Width = Unit.Percentage(15);
        tblCell.CssClass = "alt-row-hover";
        LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(dr["user_id"].ToString());

        tblCell.Controls.Add(lc);
        tblCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCell);
        mainTable.Rows.Add(tblRow);

        //To Display Detials
        TableCell tblCellDetials = new TableCell();
        tblCellDetials.CssClass = "alt-row";
        tblCellDetials.Width = Unit.Percentage(80);

        StringBuilder detailString = new StringBuilder();
        detailString.Append("Action: " + Convert.ToString(dr["action_id"]) + "<br>");
        detailString.Append("Action Date: " + Convert.ToString(dr["action_date"]) + "<br>");
        detailString.Append("Comments: " + Convert.ToString(dr["comments"]) + "<br>");

        LiteralControl lcd = new LiteralControl(detailString.ToString());

        tblCellDetials.Controls.Add(lcd);
        tblCellDetials.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCellDetials);


        DetailTable.Rows.Add(tblRow);


        return DetailTable;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the call to `BuildTable(dt)` supposed to be executed when `dt.Rows.Count > 0`? If so, it needs to be inside an `if` block. If not, please format your code accordingly.

Comment: "indentLevel is a variable declared at class level" <--- well, that's a problem. Scope it locally and pass the value (+1) *to* the function being recursed into.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have anything which *decrements* `indentLevel` at the end of `BuildTable`.

Personally, I would change `BuildTable` to take the `indentLevel` as well, and just change this:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) indentLevel = indentLevel+1; BuildTable(dt);
```

to this:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    BuildTable(dt, indentLevel + 1);
}
```

Then just call it initially with:

```
BuildTable(rootTable, 0);
```

... and remove the instance variable completely. That way you don't need to decrement `indentLevel` at all; each nested call will just naturally get the right level.

By the way, C# isn't line-based when it comes to blocks - so currently your code is equivalent to:

```
// Current code
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    indentLevel = indentLevel + 1;
}
BuildTable(dt, indentLevel);
```

That won't actually do any harm in *this* particular case, as the method does nothing when `dt.Rows` is empty, but it means your code is somewhat confusing. Personally I prefer to *always* use braces.